# Bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

Actually am using background image for all image(these are downloaded image),images are in different size so to keep this image to fit insite that background image am using create scaled bitmap.i have 38 image ,i need to display one by one when i press nextbutton as well backbutton By using imageid in xml am passing all 38 images in single xml,in this case its showing **Bitmap Exceeds VM Budget**

Answer (score 0):

try to use small size bitmap, this error occurs because of buffer

Comment: can you explain me how to do that

Comment: thats means u hav to reduce your bitamp size by using phot editor ie photoshop etc

Comment: if i try to reduce the image size it is stretchable not clear picture because all these are downloaded images

Comment: so u can put bitmap size as it is,check on DEvice not on Emulator

Comment: but in emulator my app is get crash because of this problem .Even though if it crash on emulator,whether it will work in device or what?

Comment: ya m too facing that problem, but when i running this app in my device it works fine

Answer (score 0):

**Only have what you need visible on screen loaded into memory** at one time? Don't create an array of bitmaps, or set the resources to each view in ViewFlipper, just have a viewIndex and a single set of resources already allocated (ready to be populated) of some kind and a switch to load what you need onscreen at any given time? This is the only thing I've found to help with the situation.